# ¿Como unificar validación del lado del cliente y servidor usando CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, validación

Tengo una aplicación usando JavaScript del lado del cliente (navegador web) y para el lado del servidor uso PHP con el framework CodeIgniter. 
Utilizo un formulario y tengo validaciones del lado del cliente y servidor. Lo que quisiera es tener unificado ambas validaciones en el lado del servidor. No se como hacerlo. Si alguien me puede orientar. 
Se pude hacerlo con CodeIgniter??
Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo que quieres es poder ahorrarte una validación, no?

Comment: La verdad que no es ahorrarme. Si no el tema de mantenimiento. Se hace muy engorroso estar mantenimiendo ambas partes. Tengo muchos formularios y tengo que estar validando ambos lados. Por esa razón

Comment: En función de lo que necesites validar, por ejemplo que se rellene el campo correo, que no se escriban caracteres raros, o similares, puedes validar en el cliente (JS o HTML5) y enviarlo mediante variable al php, después puedes recoger esas variables y procesarlas en el servidor, pasándole las validaciones permitenentes y aunando todo. Si nos muestras algo de código podremos ser mas precisos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta que haces no tiene una respuesta facil, pero mi aproach normalmente es validar todo por backend y devolver los errores para mostrarlos por javascript ejemplo:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "guardar", function() {
  redirect('/success');
}) .fail(function(response.error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```

y en el backend algo como:

```
<?php
```

class Form extends CI_Controller {

```
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                    array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->load->view('myform');
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
            }
    }
```

}
        ?>

Para mas información de como validar datos usando form en code igniter revisa [este link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Casi siempre mis formularios suelen venir creados por angularjs asi que para validarlos con code igniter (apartir de ci 3 antes no es posible) te conviene utilizar las validaciones para validar arrays para eso revisa [este link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post)

Comment: pero necesito validar en ambos lados. No tengo opción.

Comment: De esta forma validas solo en el servidor, mandas un ajax y devolves el error en el front end, asi estarias validando en el lado del usuario, sin tener que codear 2 veces, sino si o si tenes que mantener el codigo doble.
la opcion es hacerse un endpoint para validar nomas.

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo ? no me queda claro,

Comment: moro yo necesito validar en ambos lados. Utilizo el framework Sencha ExtJS. Estoy buscando una solución a eso. Tiene que haber alguna solución. Tu respuesta es solo en el lado del servidor y muestra los errores del lado del cliente.